# Delete multiple rows using checkbox in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-3

I have a table, which is fetching data from database correctly, Now I want to add a checkbox in front of each row in the table and submit button above the table. When I check on some checkboxes, I want to delete those rows, I was trying this code to get the ids of the selected rows, but I get nothing when I press the submit, Can you please help me out?

My View file:

```
<?= form_open('user/set_archive'); ?>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <table>
     <thead>
          <td>Action</td>
          <td>From</td>
          <td>Subject</td>
          <td>Date</td>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <?php foreach ($emails as $email) : ?>
            <tr class="read">
             <td> 
               <input type="checkbox" name='archiveval[]' id="ch<?= $email['id']; ?>" value="<?= $email['id']; ?>" >
               <label for="ch<?= $email['id']; ?>"></label>
            </td>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>....</td>                                            
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?= form_close(); ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

My Controller user/set_archive

```
public function set_archive()
{
    $data1 = $this->input->post('archiveval');
    echo "<pre>";  
    print_r($data1);

}
```

Comment: have you loaded form helper

Comment: try with `$data1 = $this->input->post('archiveval[]');`

Comment: Yes, I have loaded all the necessary libraries and helpers

Comment: This also doesn't work.

Comment: try print_r($_POST), check what you are getting

Comment: When I did this :- print_r($_POST['archiveval']);   I get A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: archiveval

Comment: print_r($_POST) don't add variable name

Comment: What you get when you try in set_archive? $data1 = $this->input->post();
  echo "<pre>";  
  print_r($data1);

Comment: Getting blank array on this :- print_r($_POST) and getting nothing on $data1 = $this->input->post(); echo "<pre>"; print_r($data1);

Comment: In the above comment were any boxes checked? Only checked checkboxes will be posted.

Comment: @Ashwani Garg, check at least one checkbox and see, i have tested its working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assignment to id is incorrect. You can get ids of the rows selected like this
`<input type="checkbox" name='archiveval[]' id="archiveval[]" value="<?= $email['id']; ?>" >`

Give it a shot